# NodeJS - How to download from a blob?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-oracledb

How can I return a file from a BLOB column using NodeJS?

I'm using the `oracledb` library to handle the database operations and I have the following code:

```
async function getFile(req, res) {

   let filename = req.params.filename;
   let file = await selectFileFromDb(filename);
   file = file.rows[0][0]; //Column that contains the blob content

   //I would like to return something like this
   res.download(file);

}
```

What should I do to read the BLOB content from the column and return as a download to the requester?

Thank you.

Comment: For reference, the node-oracledb LOB documentation is here [Working with CLOB and BLOB Data](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#lobhandling) and there are examples in the node-oracledb project directory https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send content header as the type of file that you have to download and then send the buffer (asuming what you got from the db is a buffer ) in the body . Finally end the response after sending the code. Here is a sample code .

```
async function getFile(req, res) {

   let filename = req.params.filename;
   let file = await selectFileFromDb(filename);
   file = file.rows[0][0]; //Column that contains the blob content

   res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length);
   res.write(file, 'binary');
   res.end();

}
```

**HOW TO GET THE BLOB CONTENT AS A BUFFER**

Do not forget to set the `oracledb.fetchAsBuffer` property:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.fetchAsBuffer = [oracledb.BLOB];
```

Comment: Hmmm... My "file" variable got from the select is an Object . How can I convert it to a buffer? I did not find anything in the docs yet

Comment: you can use Buffer.from to convert the string(file contents BTW) into a buffer. Buffer is also an object . when you do a console log of a buffer you will see something like this   <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f> .
Source:- https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding

Comment: I got it. I did by setting the oracledb.fetchAsBuffer = [oracledb.BLOB] option before calling oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);