# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Tags: mongodb, postman

i am not able to see the videos in my DB whenever i fetch it from postman or on the client side.

I created videos on mongoDB the videos are showing up on my database, but whenever i try to fetch it from post man or my web it doesn't show. the status on post man is (200) but no video is showing up. i also try to delete some videos although it was removed from the database but it didn't show the success message on postman.
I am am a beginner please any help will be appreciated..

this is the code for the fuction in my controller folder

```
export const random =async(req, res, next)=>{
    try {
       const videos = await Video.aggregate([{$sample: {size:40}}])

        res.status(200).json(videos)
    } catch (error) {
        next(err)
    }
}

export const sub = async(req, res, next)=>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        const subscribedChannels = user.subscribedUsers;

        const list = await Promise.all(
            subscribedChannels.map((channelId) => {
                return Video.find({userId: channelId});
            })
        );

        res.status(200).json(list.flat().sort((a,b)=>b.createdAt - a.createdAt))
        
    } catch (error) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

this is the code for the routes

```
    import express from 'express';
import { addVideo, addView, deleteVideo, getByTags, getVideo, random, search, sub,  trend, updateVideo } from '../controllers/video.js';

import { verifyToken } from '../verifyToken.js';

const router = express.Router();



router.post("/", verifyToken, addVideo)

router.put("/:id", verifyToken, updateVideo)

router.delete("/:id", verifyToken, deleteVideo)

router.get("/find/:id",  getVideo)

router.put("/view/:id",  addView)

router.get("/trend", trend)

router.get("/random",  random)

router.get("/sub", verifyToken, sub)

router.get("/tags/:id", getByTags)

router.get("/search/:id",  search)



export default router
```

Answer (score 0):

too little information about the behavior.
there could be multiple reason why it is not playing.

1. if you're using wrong way to play video (i.e. embed code is not proper in html, file is broken, encoding/decoding is not right...)
2. when you return the video data, you're using .json(). Is it json format or blob data? if so, you might need to use the other way. seems like this is a similar example: [NodeJS - How to download from a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710908/nodejs-how-to-download-from-a-blob)